# Suppress messenger chatbot notifications

Tags: notifications, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a simple chatbot answering questions from the menu.
Every time the user starts conversation ("get started"), or choses the question, which gets answered by chatbot, it creates a notification.

Is there any way to ignore messages invoked by chatbot menu (notification-wise) and only notify page admin when the user writes his own message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling notifications this granularly is not supported.